# Fetch records from table A related to data on table B

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to fetch all the tickets from tableA where tableB.tid is related to tableB.category. please note that last 2 records in tableA doesn't compliance with above condition.

```
tableA
tickets  tid   category 
124560   123   xx 
116550   125   xx
124777   244   yy
225560   223   yy
258965   244   xx
445878   123   yy
```

```
tableB
tid   category  des
123   xx        description_xx_123
223   yy        description_yy_223
125   xx        description_xx_125
244   yy        description_yy_223
```

Result expected is

```
tableA
tickets
124560 
116550 
124777
225560
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `exists`:

```
select a.*
from tabla a
where exists (select 1
              from tableb b
              where a.tid = b.tid and a.category = b.category
             );
```

This ignores duplicates in `tableb`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do an inner join it will only return the results in both tables.

```
select a.tickets
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.tid = b.tid and a.category = b.category
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a join for this

```
SELECT tableA.tickets FROM tableA
JOIN tableB  
ON tableA.tid = tableB.tid 
AND tableA.category = tableB.category
```

Can use a where clause as well

```
SELECT tableA.tickets FROM tableA, tableB  
WHERE tableA.tid = tableB.tid 
AND tableA.category = tableB.category
```